# Why in JS arrayTest[undefined] is valid

Tags: javascript

Recently I discovered that arrayTest[undefined] = 'something' and arrayTest[null] = 'something' are actually valid in javascript. Have a look at the bottom code.

```
var arrayTest = [];
var someText = 'someText';

arrayTest[undefined] = 'undefined';
arrayTest[null] = 'null';
arrayTest[someText] = 'someText';

// ReferenceError: someUndefinedText is not defined
//arrayTest[someUndefinedText] = 'someUndefinedText';

console.log(arrayTest);
//[ undefined: 'undefined', null: 'null', someText: 'someText' ]
```

Does somebody has logical explanation why this piece of code is valid. And why trying to insert something inside array by explicitly setting it's key to undefined is valid and inserting something in array by setting it's key to some undefined variable is not valid.

NOTE: Tested by node v0.12.2

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you get from console.log()?

Comment: yes you can try by yourself

Comment: For what it's worth, Firefox shows an empty array `[]` in the console. Are you sure `arrayTest` is not an object (`{}`)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: all arrays are objects, but the Firefox console might not show non-numeric properties of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between a variable being undefined (which is usually easier to think of as being an undeclared variable) and a variable having the *value* of the `undefined` object. (The variable `undefined` has the `undefined` object as its default value).

Trying to read from the former will throw a reference error, trying to read from the latter will give you the `undefined` object.

When you access a property with square bracket notation, you have to pass a string or something that can be converted to a string. The `undefined` object converts to the string `"undefined"` (`"" + undefined === "undefined"`).

```
// ReferenceError: someUndefinedText is not defined
//arrayTest[someUndefinedText] = 'someUndefinedText';
```

`arrayTest` is largely irrelevant here. The error comes from trying to *read* the variable `someUndefinedText` to get a string to use as a property name.

Comment: Are you sure about "The undefined object has a toString()", if you are can you explain me why undefined.toString() do not work ? Ok now with you edit it's true. It's due to a dynamic conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this

```
var arrayTest = [];
var someText = 'someText';

arrayTest[undefined] = 'undefined';
arrayTest[null] = 'null';
arrayTest[someText] = 'someText';

// ReferenceError: someUndefinedText is not defined
//arrayTest[someUndefinedReference] = 'someUndefinedText';

var bar; // test hold undefined value
arrayTest[bar] = 'foo'; // replace the value 'undefined' at index undefined by 'foo'
console.log(arrayTest);
```

It's because in javascript null and undefined are value. So Javascript don't see the problem.
When you don't declare you variable, it's not the same as setting undefined or null. It's a ReferenceError where no value can't be found at this reference and no reference != undefined